# can't reload page after having two cookies

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, setcookie

Why I can't reload the same page after I create two cookies by setcookie() function?
The page kept on loading to timeout after reload,no any error message in apache log and nothing in chrome developer tool.
The problem maybe crashed with javascript,because I removed the  line in HTML,the page can load,any method to correct this bug?

this is code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<?php include "**cookie2.php**";?>
<!--other content in head-->
</head>
<body>
**<!--a button onclick will run cookie1.php-->**
<!--other contents in body-->
<script src="**readcookie1.js**" language="javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>

in file **cookie1.php**
{
**setcookie("login",1,0,"/");**
}

in file **cookie2.php**
{
**setcookie("pageView",0,0,"/");**
}

in file **readcookie1.js**
{
//use **document.cookie** to get cookie2
}
```

Comment: Share your code too

Comment: Without seeing the code in question we're not able to help you.

Comment: I have added my code.

Answer (score 0):

oh,I found the problem.
My function to read cookies in javascript had bug,so process stuck there.I have revised it.